# Dont allow view to increase its size depending on contents

Tags: react-native

Im new to react-native. I have just created a reusable component of text input as I want.
Im using that reusable component into a view. At one place Im adding reusable component 4 times, and at another place 7 times.

example :

```
<Textinput
        style={styles.textInput}
        secureTextEntry={false}
        textInputName={'USERNAME'}
        showBottomBorder={true}
        height={45}
        onTextChange={this.onTextChangeUsername}
        />
```

using above code 7 times in view , causes increase of size of the view.
But I dont want to allow this at it looks ugly on iPhone 4s screen.

So is there any way to disallow that ? Or rather can I give height to reusable component depending upon its parent view's height ?

Like , height={parentView.height/7} ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly how to solve your problem, but if you wanted to add a custom width/height component that depended on the size of the div, you could do something like this with a class function:

resizeGraphs(){

```
        var div = document.getElementsByClassName("yourcontainer")
        if (div[0] != undefined){
            var divWidth = document.getElementsByClassName("yourcontainer")[0].clientWidth //or .clientHeight
            this.setState({
                divWidth,
            })}}
```

To explain, this will be called in componentDidMount (I guess you don't have to worry about window resizing). It gets the width of a given class and you can scale your inner elements appropriately as you suggested.

I guess warning flags should be going off if you see direct references to the DOM in react, but I wasn't sure how else to solve this. If anyone has a more "react-y" solution i'd love to see it..